# Script issue - JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Tags: python

have some issues with a livescore problem that gets information from livescore

```
  File "/home/sop/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sopel/bot.py", line 763, in call_rule
    rule.execute(sopel, trigger)
  File "/home/sop/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sopel/plugins/rules.py", line 1057, in execute
    exit_code = self._handler(bot, trigger)
  File "/home/sop/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sopel/plugin.py", line 1071, in guarded
    return function(bot, trigger, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sop/.sopel/plugins/livescores.py", line 310, in var
    data = get_match_info(id)
  File "/home/sop/.sopel/plugins/livescores.py", line 82, in get_match_info
    json = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
  File "/home/sop/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And part of the script below:

```
def get_match_info(id):
    data = {}
    url = f'https://prod-public-api.livescore.com/v1/api/app/match/soccer/{id}/0.0'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'TE': 'Trailers',
    }
    json = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    kickoff = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(json['Esd']), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    kickoff_utc = kickoff.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
    kickoff_ro = kickoff_utc.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Bucharest'))
    data['country'] = json['Stg']['Cnm']
    data['Esd'] = json['Esd']
    data['league'] = json['Stg']['Snm']
    if json['Eps'] == 'NS':
        data['time'] = ("Kick Off: " + str(kickoff_ro.time())[:-3])
    else:
        data['time'] = json['Eps']
    data['home_team'] = json['T1'][0]['Nm']
    data['home_score'] = json['Tr1'] if "Tr1" in json else "0"
    data['away_team'] = json['T2'][0]['Nm']
    data['away_score'] = json['Tr2'] if "Tr2" in json else "0"
    data['refs'] = json['Refs'][0]['Nm'] if "Refs" in json else 'VAR'

    return data
```

Anyone able to help please?
The script is bigger, please tell me if you need more info.

Dont know much about the issue.

Comment: Check the HTTP code of the response before parsing the JSON.

Comment: Thanks Klaus. what do you mean please? Im a begginer in all this./// Problem is that it worked until 2 days ago and nothing has been changed

Comment: Basicaly the site is this: https://prod-public-api.livescore.com/v1/api/app/date/soccer/20230407/0.0